# How do I force re-execution of a function in a jinja2 template?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I am a GAE/Python newbie.

I have a jinja2 template that calls a customer filter function:

The call looks as follows:

```
{% if constant-parameter|AccessOK %} 
    <li><a href="/tokens-step1">Tokens</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

I have defined the filter on the page the render template is called:

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_environment = \
    jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True, loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(TEMPLATE_DIR))
jinja_environment.filters['AccessOK'] = AccessOK
```

When I run this, it filter is called the first time I access the web site after starting the app engine (I have logging entries).

The filter is never called again when I access other pages or refresh a page.

I need the filter to execute on every page view.

I have been told this is because the parameter is a constant and that if I change it to a variable, it will execute each time.  In my case I need to pass the constant, so I tried passing 2 parameters (whereby the variable = currentuser and exists only to trick the system into executing the filter each time).

I get an error indicating that the system is not recognizing the 2nd parameter.

Can anyone tell me how I can ensure the customer filter is called every time or give me an example of how I can pass 2 parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but it works.

I added a changing variable as an additional parameter (in this case currentuser).  This meant I had to pass 2 parameters.

My Template statement now looks like:

```
{% if currentuser|AccessOK(constant-parameter) %} 
    <li><a href="/tokens-step1">Tokens</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

And my function looks like this:

```
def AccessOK(xCurrentUser, PermissionID):
```

And I ignore the xCurrentUser parameter in my function.

If anyone has a better solution please add it.

Thanks.